# Menu does not overflow

Tags: css, overflow

I am trying to create a vertical menu but struggle with an overflow problem. Or actually with the problem of not overflowing.
In the static shape all the Buttons should have the same width.

When hovering over one of the buttons I want to move the text and the right border of the button `4px` to the right (which means also the container width increases by `4px`).
I tried to do this by adding `4px` padding to the left within the anchor container, which should make the container overflow `4px` to the right.

When hovering over "Zagreb" it should look sth like this:

_________
|Split.........|
|________|__
|...Zagreb........|
|___________|
|Zadar.......|
|________|
|Makarska|
|________|

But it doesn't overflow, instead see what happens:
http://jsfiddle.net/6vxsh61h/1/

**SOLUTION**

Ok I got it fixed with the `margin-right: -4px` trick.
http://jsfiddle.net/6vxsh61h/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add to the a:hover rules

```
a:hover {
    margin-right: -4px;
}
```

Just adding that one rule to the jsfiddle you posted has the effect you wanted as I understand it

Comment: Actually had tried that before but I thought there must be a more "proper" way to handle that.
Also I had problems doind the same when the menu is right aligned. But I now managed to do it both ways. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Increase width on hover, e.g.

```
a:hover {
width:105%;
  background: rgb(120,216,230);
  box-shadow: 0px 0 5px 1px grey !important;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6vxsh61h/4/

Answer (score 0):

You made your `<a>` elements block elements, which is fine, but by default, they will be automatically setup with border-box-esque box-sizing. This means that they will be autosized to fit the width of the container, minus the padding that you define. This way, they will always fill the width of the container.

To fix this, you only need to define a width:

```
a
{
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6vxsh61h/2/)

Comment: The problem here is when you hover over "Makarska" the container  the width changes. Wunth's way worked though.

Comment: What I wonder though is that I tried changing box-sizing of the anchors back to content-box, but that didn't work. Any Idea why?